# Linux Find command using +mtime gives incorrect results

Tags: linux, find, filemtime

I am using find to list files older than 21 days so they can be moved or deleted.

I have a list of 80 files with dates ranging from 28/12/2017 to 11/01/2017

If I issue the command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.ABC*' -type f -mtime +7
    -rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  11K Dec 29 04:53 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Dec 29 04:53 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.9K Dec 29 04:11 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Dec 29 04:14 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  12K Dec 29 16:09 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 16:10 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 27 06:03 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 06:06 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 27 15:06 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 15:08 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 22:43 ./FILESH20171228034212.ABC501141.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.1K Dec 28 21:17 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Dec 28 21:17 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Dec 29 01:49 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 01:50 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.3K Dec 29 06:08 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 06:08 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Dec 29 12:22 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 12:22 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 29 13:11 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 29 13:13 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 6.3K Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  231 Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 6.3K Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  231 Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3.1K Dec 28 21:12 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Dec 28 21:14 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639.err
```

I get a list of the files older than 7 days

If I issue the command

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.ABC*' -type f -mtime +21

-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Jan  9 03:44 ./FILEDETAEDXB.ABC0006309.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  11K Jan  2 04:40 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  2 04:40 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  11K Jan  2 05:41 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  2 05:43 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.4K Jan  5 06:23 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0833717
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  5 06:25 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0833717.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.4K Jan 10 02:30 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0835828
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan 10 02:30 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0835828.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  11K Dec 29 04:53 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Dec 29 04:53 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.9K Dec 29 04:11 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Dec 29 04:14 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.9K Jan  2 02:16 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  2 02:16 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.6K Jan  4 06:58 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136566
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  4 07:00 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136566.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.6K Jan  5 03:31 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136644
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  5 03:31 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136644.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.6K Jan  7 05:54 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136957
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  7 05:56 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136957.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.6K Jan  9 08:30 ./FILEDETFRCDG.ABC0925054
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  9 08:32 ./FILEDETFRCDG.ABC0925054.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 9.4K Jan  8 10:30 ./FILEDETGBLHR.ABC0924523
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  235 Jan  8 10:31 ./FILEDETGBLHR.ABC0924523.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  12K Jan  5 20:47 ./FILEDETUSIND.ABC1079659
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  230 Jan  5 20:47 ./FILEDETUSIND.ABC1079659.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  12K Dec 29 16:09 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 16:10 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 27 06:03 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 06:06 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 27 15:06 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 15:08 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 27 22:43 ./FILESH20171228034212.ABC501141.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.1K Dec 28 21:17 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Dec 28 21:17 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Dec 29 01:49 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 01:50 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.3K Dec 29 06:08 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 06:08 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Dec 29 12:22 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Dec 29 12:22 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Dec 29 13:11 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Dec 29 13:13 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 6.3K Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  231 Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 6.3K Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  231 Dec 30 09:07 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.3K Jan  2 06:03 ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Jan  2 06:04 ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 7.1K Jan  4 08:53 ./FILESH20180104135324.ABC526871
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  223 Jan  4 08:54 ./FILESH20180104135324.ABC526871.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 1.6K Jan  5 11:23 ./FILESH20180105162316.ABC532119
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  194 Jan  5 11:25 ./FILESH20180105162316.ABC532119.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.8K Jan  5 19:03 ./FILESH20180106000302.ABC533625
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  231 Jan  5 19:05 ./FILESH20180106000302.ABC533625.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Jan  7 10:50 ./FILESH20180107155028.ABC537128
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Jan  7 10:50 ./FILESH20180107155028.ABC537128.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.1K Jan  8 12:30 ./FILESH20180108173029.ABC541273
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Jan  8 12:31 ./FILESH20180108173029.ABC541273.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.3K Jan  9 05:00 ./FILESH20180109100016.ABC544589
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  220 Jan  9 05:02 ./FILESH20180109100016.ABC544589.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.3K Jan 10 02:07 ./FILESH20180110070732.ABC549496
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  307 Jan 10 02:09 ./FILESH20180110070732.ABC549496.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.1K Jan 10 04:34 ./FILEFRCDG.ABC0925588
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan 10 04:36 ./FILEFRCDG.ABC0925588.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 4.1K Jan 10 08:08 ./FILEFRCDG.ABC0925774
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan 10 08:09 ./FILEFRCDG.ABC0925774.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 2.8K Jan  6 02:48 ./FILEHKHKG.ABC0002019
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan  6 02:50 ./FILEHKHKG.ABC0002019.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3.1K Dec 28 21:12 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Dec 28 21:14 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 5.1K Jan  2 19:31 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan  2 19:33 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3.8K Jan  5 20:20 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043212
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan  5 20:20 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043212.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3.1K Jan 10 01:29 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043467
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan 10 01:30 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043467.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser 3.1K Jan 10 02:04 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043479
-rw-r--r-- 1 myuser myuser  274 Jan 10 02:06 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0043479.err
```

I get a list of all of the files as none were matched, I would have expected 0 files to show. This is no good to me if I want to delete on a rolling basis as it will delete everything.

Is this just a the default behaviour using mtime (checked the man pages and didn't find any relevant comments)?

Comment: "I get a list of all of the files as none were matched, this is obviously no good to me if I want to delete on a rolling basis as it will delete everything." What exactly does this mean? I've got a hard time understanding this sentence, what you intend to do and which results you expect. Please rephrase and add examples.

Comment: edited to add filelists

Answer (score 0):

From the second list of files from your question I have recreated files in the directory, so it looks like this:

```
[/tmp/10]$ cat /tmp/2 | awk '{print $6,$7,$8,$9}' | while read a b c file; do touch -m -t $(date --date="$(if [ "$a" == Jan ]; then echo "2018-01-$b $c:00"; else echo "2017-12-$b $c:00"; echo $b >&2; fi)" +%Y%m%d%H00) "$file"; done
[/tmp/10]$ ls -lat  --time-style=long-iso
total 0
drwxrwxrwt 18 root  root   520 2018-01-11 14:34 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 kamil kamil 1640 2018-01-11 14:30 ./
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 08:00 FILEFRCDG.ABC0925774
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 08:00 FILEFRCDG.ABC0925774.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 04:00 FILEFRCDG.ABC0925588
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 04:00 FILEFRCDG.ABC0925588.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0835828
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0835828.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043479
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043479.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILESH20180110070732.ABC549496
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 02:00 FILESH20180110070732.ABC549496.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 01:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043467
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-10 01:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043467.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-09 08:00 FILEDETFRCDG.ABC0925054
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-09 08:00 FILEDETFRCDG.ABC0925054.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-09 05:00 FILESH20180109100016.ABC544589
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-09 05:00 FILESH20180109100016.ABC544589.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-09 03:00 FILEDETAEDXB.ABC0006309.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-08 12:00 FILESH20180108173029.ABC541273
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-08 12:00 FILESH20180108173029.ABC541273.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-08 10:00 FILEDETGBLHR.ABC0924523
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-08 10:00 FILEDETGBLHR.ABC0924523.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-07 10:00 FILESH20180107155028.ABC537128
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-07 10:00 FILESH20180107155028.ABC537128.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-07 05:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136957
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-07 05:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136957.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-06 02:00 FILEHKHKG.ABC0002019
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-06 02:00 FILEHKHKG.ABC0002019.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 20:00 FILEDETUSIND.ABC1079659
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 20:00 FILEDETUSIND.ABC1079659.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 20:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043212
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 20:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0043212.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 19:00 FILESH20180106000302.ABC533625
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 19:00 FILESH20180106000302.ABC533625.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 11:00 FILESH20180105162316.ABC532119
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 11:00 FILESH20180105162316.ABC532119.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 06:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0833717
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 06:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0833717.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 03:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136644
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-05 03:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136644.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-04 08:00 FILESH20180104135324.ABC526871
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-04 08:00 FILESH20180104135324.ABC526871.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-04 07:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136566.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-04 06:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136566
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 19:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0042904
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 19:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0042904.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 06:00 FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 06:00 FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 05:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 05:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 04:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 04:00 FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 02:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2018-01-02 02:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-30 09:00 FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-30 09:00 FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-30 09:00 FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-30 09:00 FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 16:00 FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 16:00 FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 13:00 FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 13:00 FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 12:00 FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 12:00 FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 06:00 FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 06:00 FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 04:00 FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 04:00 FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 04:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 04:00 FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 01:00 FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-29 01:00 FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-28 21:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0042639
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-28 21:00 FILESGSIN.ABC0042639.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-28 21:00 FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-28 21:00 FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-27 22:00 FILESH20171228034212.ABC501141.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-27 15:00 FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-27 15:00 FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980.err
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-27 06:00 FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058
-rw-r--r--  1 kamil kamil    0 2017-12-27 06:00 FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058.err
```

Running `-mtime +7`:

```
[/tmp/10]$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.ABC*' -type f -mtime +7 | xargs ls -lat --time-style=long-iso
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 19:00 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 19:00 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 06:00 ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 06:00 ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 05:00 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 05:00 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 04:00 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 04:00 ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 02:00 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2018-01-02 02:00 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-30 09:00 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-30 09:00 ./FILESH20171230140743.ABC511960.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-30 09:00 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-30 09:00 ./FILESH20171230140744.ABC511961.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 16:00 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 16:00 ./FILEDETUSMIA.ABC1076077.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 13:00 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 13:00 ./FILESH20171229181138.ABC509510.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 12:00 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 12:00 ./FILESH20171229172209.ABC509285.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 06:00 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 06:00 ./FILESH20171229110823.ABC507313.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 04:00 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 04:00 ./FILEDETDKKPH.ABC0135779.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 04:00 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 04:00 ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0135771.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 01:00 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-29 01:00 ./FILESH20171229064908.ABC506346.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-28 21:00 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-28 21:00 ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042639.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-28 21:00 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-28 21:00 ./FILESH20171229021743.ABC505716.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-27 22:00 ./FILESH20171228034212.ABC501141.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-27 15:00 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-27 15:00 ./FILESH20171227200641.ABC499980.err
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-27 06:00 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058
-rw-r--r-- 1 kamil kamil 0 2017-12-27 06:00 ./FILESH20171227110357.ABC498058.err
```

gives me a few more files, but maybe it is 2 hours later:

```
[/tmp/10]$ diff <(cat /tmp/1 | awk '{print $9}' | sort) <(find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.ABC*' -type f -mtime +7 | sort)
0a1,4
> ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923
> ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831923.err
> ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948
> ./FILEDETDEFFM.ABC0831948.err
4a9,10
> ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108
> ./FILEDETESPMI.ABC0136108.err
8a15,16
> ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904
> ./FILESGSIN.ABC0042904.err
27a36,37
> ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782
> ./FILESH20180102110316.ABC517782.err
```

Anyway running `-mtime +21` gives me no results.

```
[/tmp/10]$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.ABC*' -type f -mtime +21
[/tmp/10]$
```

I have put the code on tutorialspoint.com http://tpcg.io/OgKDKc

I can guess that:

- your find utility is somewhat broken.
- time on your system is not stable and bad.
- files modification times showed in your listings are not modification times, but access or creation times. Maybe you are using `ls -u` to list the files or your ls utility is broken.
- i have failed to recreate the conditions

PS. In your question I assumed you meant '11/01/2018' and not '11/01/2017'.